# negative value from Android getLocationOnScreen

Tags: android

I found the value from View.getLocationOnScreen could be a negative value. However, it explains: "Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen. The argument must be an array of two integers. After the method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order.". So it should always be a value of positive value.

Comment: Nothing there implies the array will contain positive values. Negative x/y values are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you an example where you'll have a negative value.

Let's say that you're working on an app where you want to have some fragments moving around. Maybe have new fragments slide in from the left, and the old fragment slide out on the right.

When you create your new fragment, you don't want it to appear right on the screen! You need to create it at a negative x, so that is off the the left of the screen, then animate it to slide in. So if you try to get the x of the new fragment before it has started sliding, you'll get a negative value.

A negative location just means that whatever object has the negative location is off the screen.

Comment: Thanks man... negative means either left, right , down or top side but out of screen